# Android messages is able to display an image from a webpage without OG:Image. how does it accomplish this?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta

I have been working with OG:Image and OG:Title. It seems that all web pages do not add this but this is still able to be deciphered by Android Messages. Any idea how it is able to accomplish this. I have analyzed the source of the website and cannot identify how it is able to.

Example

```
https://www.acer.com/ac/es/MX/content/predator-thronos-air
```

Meta Tags

```
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user- 
     scalable=no"> 
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="none"> 
<meta name="robots" content="noydir"> 
<meta name="robots" content="noodp"> 
<meta name="sectionName" content="#">
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Many apps and social sites (e.g. Facebook) will look for og tags (Open Graph). If they can’t find any, they’ll look for the title and meta description tag. If there’s no description tag, they’ll search for a p tag. For the image, they’ll grab the first suitable image on the site. Android grabs a large image while Facebook grabs a smaller image that’s listed earlier on the page. The apps and sites’ responsibility is to provide a rich link preview with as much info as possible. If the site designer doesn’t make that info available, the app or site will do what they can with what they can find.

Comment: Thank you rich. That is very informative. I wasn't sure where I should looking for the content and your recommendations seem pretty straight forward.